# Extract the Map <K,V> an object of type parameters passed

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I get an object as parameter and want to compare the key of the object with an array of Strings.

the object is of type `Map <String, byte[]>`

```
String [] keys = {"a", "b"}
```

Sorry for the absence, I had no opportunity to come here so I'll try to explain exactly what I want. I receive an object via the socket, then go through the object parameter to the method readObject.

Map In this method I have to separate the "K" (keys) and insert them into different Map. for eg:

```
Map 1 (String [] = {1 map "a", "f", "c", "d"};

Map 2 (String [] {map = 2 "and", "i", "o", "k"};

main class

{ //...

S.getInputStream InputStream is =..... ();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ......;

MapObject mo = (MapObject) ois.readObject ();

//-----> ReadObject (mo)

... }

public static MapObject readObject (MapObject mo) {

String [] map1 = { "a", "f", "c", "d"};
```

is it possible? ----> MapObject mapi = mo;

He bursts in the next step

this ------->

```
Map map = (Map ) mo;

    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet ()) {

     Entry.getKey key = String ();

     byte [] value = entry.getValue ();

     if (test.equals (entry.getKey ()))
     {

          map.put (key, value);
      }

        }

    } 
    public void readObject(Object parObj)
    {

      Here I want to extract the key from parObj comparable to do with the String []

      for example an if ().

      finally extract unable to insert a value to put (Key, Value);

    }
```

My difficulty lies in extracting the key and value.

Some suggestions or tip to achieve my objective?

Thank you for your attention and availability

Comment: Why not just change the parameter's type to `Map<String, byte[]>`?

Comment: I'll have to explain.

I am required to pass the socket object and then use a put method that takes as parameters String and value.

Comment: You need to put more detail and explain it better. The post as of now is really confusing.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I guess `java.io.Serializable` plays a role here.

Comment: @BalusC That's what I was thinking, but since the OP never actually stated that, I didn't want to make a bad assumption.

Comment: I have a class with one that is of type hashmap serializable but Yurib could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood the question, you first need to cast the object to a `Map` so you can use the map interace, then you can iterate over all the entries and do whatever you need.

```
Map<String, byte[]> m = (Map)parObj;
for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : m.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  byte[] value = entry.getValue();
  // do whatever you need with the key and value...
}
```

Comment: Successful in helping me a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clarification on this might be a little helpful; I don't really understand what you're after.

The javadoc for Map is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

That said, here's my best shot.

Also, as @Jeffrey states, you should be passing a Map, not an Object.

```
public void class Foo{
    private String[] keys  {"a", "b"};

    public void readObject(Map<String, byte[]> parObj){
        boolean foundAnyKey = false;
        for(String key : keys){
            if(parObj.containsKey(key) == true){
                 foundAnyKey = true;
                 byte[] values = parObj.get(key);
                 *<do something special with the values>*
            }
        }

        if(foundAnyKey == true){
           *<do something special, 'cause you found a key>*
        }//--for(...)

    }//--readObject(...)
}//--Foo{..}
```